# What is the origin of the word "mojosa"?

Tags: etymology

How did this relatively new word come into use? Is it accepted as an official Esperanto word?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the Esperanto Wikipedia article [Mojosa](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojosa):

> La vorto ekestis en novembro de 2003 dum la TEJK-seminario en Söjtör (Hungario) per iniciato de Gregor Hinker, Felix Zesch, Carl Mäsak kaj ceteraj seminarianoj, kiam oni konstatis la fortan mankon de esperanto-vorto kiu signifus la samon kiel la angla vorto *cool*, sed ne en la laŭvorta senco (*malvarmeta*), sed en alia (*moderna*, *bonega*). Malkiel multaj aliaj proponoj pri slangaĵoj, ĝi ekuziĝis kaj enradikiĝis, unue inter junuloj, sed intertempe ankaŭ pli kaj pli en la pli aĝaj generacioj.
>
> La seminaria laborgrupo konstatis, ke la esenco de la angla vorto *cool* tradukeblas kiel *modernjunstila* (emfazante tiel al moderneco, juneco kaj stileco), sed ĉar tion oni konstatis tro komplika, tro longa kaj ne tro *cool*-a, oni anstataŭe prenis la komencajn literojn de ĉiu de la tri radikoj (**m**odern' - **j**un' - **s**til') kaj el ili kreis mallongigon *MJS*, kiu (laŭ sia po-litera elparolo) provizis bazon por la nova adjektivo *mojosa*.
>
> Ekzistantaj klarigoj pri tio, kiel ne eblis iu *pli rekta* esperantigo de la vorto *cool* kialigas, ke fonetika transpreno *kula* kreus konfuzon kun kuloj kaj transpreno de la baza signifo *frida* ne taŭgas pro tio, ke ĝi kaŭzus dusensecon.

The word can now be found in multiple widely respected dictionaries (e.g. ReVo and John Well's Concise Dictionary), but it is not yet recognized by the Esperanto Academy. (I'm not even sure whether such a recognition would make much sense; one point about using such a word is that it has a slangy character, and that would kind of get lost if the word became officially recognised by the Academy.)

Answer (score 6):

*mojosa* means MOderna-Juna-Stila (modern-young-stylish). It's an accepted Esperanto word and the most popular way to say *cool* in Esperanto.

> -- Mi havas grandajn ruĝajn ŝuojn!
>
> -- Estas mojose!

Here the last sentence means *'It is cool!'*

Comment: I've usually seen this written together as modernjunstila as in the very in-depth treatment of this on the Esperanto Wikipedia: https://eo.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojosa

Comment: It would be good to clarify what is meant by “accepted”. If it is not in PIV then perhaps it is not completely official yet.

Comment: It is "accepted" because people use it, especially young people.