# Are there words in Esperanto that are occuring only in Esperanto and aren't drawn from other languages?

Tags: etymology

[This question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/344/are-there-any-esperanto-words-derived-from-words-from-non-indo-european-language) asks for Esperanto words taken from non-Indo-European languages. Here I want to know: Are there Esperanto words that are not taken from any previously existing language, but are created specifically for Esperanto? What are examples of them?

Right out of my mind I can think of Usono "USA", are there more of them?

Comment: Usono is apparently derived from English. See [this question](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/220/what-is-the-origin-of-usono).

Comment: Suggestion: could you change the title with a short version.

Comment: @Ben1001 why? The title seems fine to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some affixes don't bear obvious resemblance to equivalents in other languages, such e.g. *ul*. The correlatives are also mostly *a priori*: some prefixes, such as *neni-* or *ki-*, are probably influenced by other languages, but no other language Zamenhof knew of has words close to *ĉiam* or *iu*.

*Edzo* also doesn't have a clear origin. Wiktionary says about *edzino*:

> Perhaps a back-formation from Yiddish רביצין ‎(*rebetsin*, “rebbetzin, rabbi's wife”). Zamenhof's explanation that it was from German *Kronprinz**essin*** ‎(“Crown Princess”) is thought to have been an attempt to avoid antisemitism. Reanalysed as *edzo* ‎(“husband, spouse”) +‎ *-ino* ‎(feminine suffix).

It seems very convoluted to me.

Comment: -ul- might be approached with the latin root [-ulus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ulus), used for create diminutives nouns, that you might find in derived words like *credulous* (en), crédule (fr) that would both be translated in Esperanto to *kredema*, rather than *kredula*. While *ulo* alone have, according to PIV, a pejorative connotation, -ul- doesn't seems to carry it.

Comment: I don't find this particularly convoluted: if you ignore the bit about *Kronprinzessin* (which is hurdle for the theory that Zamenhof plucked *edzo* out of thin air, too), it's just saying the word *edzino* comes from *rebetsin*, and then the *-in* suffix was removed to make the male version.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, although there are not much of them. While the correlative table has inspiration in other languages, some words in the table have no derivation at all from other languages, and instead come completely out of the applied system in Esperanto, like "iom".

Also some derived words have nothing to do any more with the original components, like necesejo.

([Usono comes from the English Usonia](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/220/what-is-the-origin-of-usono), which only had limited popularity in English.)

Answer (score 4):

Many of the affix based ones, for example: "umadi", "ilaro", "ege", "mala", ...

Comment: *Mala* seems to be based on the Romance root mal-, even though it changed its meaning in the process of borrowing.

Answer (score 4):

How about **kabei**?

Kabei is a verb that comes from the Esperanto name of Kazimierz Bein, Kabe. So it's not *directly* derived from any particular language unless you'd want to count the etymology of Kabe's non-Esperanto name.

---

Here's kabei defined, if anyone's curious:

From vortaro.net:

> **kabei**. Agi kiel Kabe, kiu, estante tre vigla E-isto, subite k tute ĉesis verki en E.

In English, translated by me:

> To act like Kabe, who, having been a very active Esperantist, suddenly and completely stopped working (writing) in Esperanto.

Personally I have seen and used this word occasionally not just for leaving the Esperanto movement suddenly, but for being active and making a considerable effort for any type of movement/cause and then suddenly dropping it, or sometimes simply to describe being interested in something and participating in it for a time but then losing interest and "disappearing" from the scene.

Answer (score 4):

Another good and widely-used example is probably ‘mojosa’, whose origins are explained e.g. here: [What is the origin of the word "mojosa"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/66/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-mojosa?rq=1)